# Join two simple queries in Bigquery

Tags: sql, join, count, google-bigquery

Here's the 1st query

```
SELECT
  MONTH(TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '.*.([0-9]{4})$') + '-' +
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '.([0-9]{2}).') + '-' +
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '^([0-9]{2}).*'))) AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT cons_id)
FROM
  [table1]
WHERE
  dbo_type = 'smth'
GROUP BY month
```

returning users' ids grouped by month.
Here's the 2nd one

```
SELECT
  MONTH(TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '.*.([0-9]{4})$') + '-' +
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '.([0-9]{2}).') + '-' +
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '^([0-9]{2}).*'))) AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT cons_id)
FROM
  [table1]
WHERE
  dbo_type = 'smth'
  AND success_operations > 0
GROUP BY month
```

returning **active** users' ids grouped by same months. How do join them in order to get a simple table like

```
month | users     | active_users
------| --------- | ---------
9     | 100       | 50
10    | 120       | 60
11    | 140       | 70
```

--- ANSWER ----

Thanks, Michael!

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  INTEGER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(DATE, '.([0-9]{2}).')) AS month,
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(cons_id) AS users, 
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(IF(success_operations  > 0, cons_id, NULL)) AS active_users
FROM
  [project:dataset.table]
WHERE
  dbo_type = 'smth'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below for BigQuery Legacy SQL (as looks like you are using it in your question)

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  MONTH(TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '.*.([0-9]{4})$') + '-' +
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '.([0-9]{2}).') + '-' +
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '^([0-9]{2}).*'))) AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT cons_id) AS users, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(success_operations  > 0, cons_id, NULL)) AS active_users
FROM
  [project:dataset.table1]
WHERE
  dbo_type = 'smth'
GROUP BY month
```

Please note: COUNT(DISTINCT) in Legacy SQL is approximate - see more details - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#countdistinct

You can use [EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#exact_count_distinct) instead

Also, it looks to me that instead of lengthy

```sql
  MONTH(TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '.*.([0-9]{4})$') + '-' +
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '.([0-9]{2}).') + '-' +
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '^([0-9]{2}).*'))) AS month
```

you can use just

```sql
INTEGER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(DATE, '.([0-9]{2}).'))
```

For BigQuery Standard SQL you can try below:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(DATE, '.([0-9]{2}).') AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT cons_id) AS users, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(success_operations  > 0, cons_id, NULL)) AS active_users
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable`
WHERE dbo_type = 'smth'
GROUP BY month
```

You can test / play with it using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourTable` AS (
  SELECT '31-12-2017' DATE, 1 cons_id, 1 success_operations, 'smth' dbo_type UNION ALL
  SELECT '31-12-2017', 2, 0, 'smth' UNION ALL
  SELECT '31-12-2017', 3, 0, 'smth'
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(DATE, '.([0-9]{2}).') AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT cons_id) AS users, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(success_operations  > 0, cons_id, NULL)) AS active_users
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable`
WHERE dbo_type = 'smth'
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The aggregate function MONTH works only for legacy SQL. As well as REGEXP_EXTRACT

Comment: oh, I missed this  - was focusing on how to count - will re-answer this one shortly. please clarify - do yo need it in Legacy or Standard? can you give example of your date field?

Comment: you can consider migrating to Standard SQL - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql . In Standard SQL COUNT(DISTINCT) produces exact distinct count as one would normally expect

Comment: For my and other users' consideration. Could write the same query using #standardSQL dialect?

Comment: added version for BigQuery Standard SQL - assuming I got your date field format correctly :o) - DD-MM-YYYY